# How to fix the time format into hh:mm:ss and automatic add 15 minutes in finish time? I have two text boxes here

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

//This is the two text boxes, where I can select time using timepicker. I want it to make the format into hh:mm:ss and I want to add in finish_time an automatic 15 minutes.

```
        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
            <label class="required" for="start_time">{{ trans('cruds.workingHour.fields.start_time') }}</label>
            <input class="form-control {{ $errors->has('start_time') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="text" name="start_time" id="start_time" value="{{ old('start_time') }}" required>
            @if($errors->has('start_time'))
                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('start_time') }}</span>
            @endif
            <span class="help-block">{{ trans('cruds.workingHour.fields.start_time_helper') }}</span>
        </div>
```

```
        <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
            <label class="required" for="finish_time">{{ trans('cruds.workingHour.fields.finish_time') }}</label>
            <input class="form-control{{ $errors->has('finish_time') ? 'is-invalid' : '' }}" type="text" name="finish_time" id="finish_time" value="{{ old('finish_time') }}" required readonly>
            @if($errors->has('finish_time'))
                <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('finish_time') }}</span>
            @endif
            <span class="help-block">{{ trans('cruds.workingHour.fields.finish_time_helper') }}</span>
        </div>
```

//example, I insert in timepicker jquery; 10:00:00 and it will end at 10:15:00

Comment: Maybe this post could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882582/how-to-add-2-hours-for-end-time-on-previously-changed-start-using-jquery-time

Comment: What are these `@` things? What templating language is this?